# How do I prove a quadratic expression to always be negative for all real values of x

Tags: quadratics

So in school we are learning about quadratics. But I'm very confused on how to prove the question above.

Example: $-x^{2}+x-2$

How would I prove that the expression is negative for all real values of x for expression above.

Comment: Plenty of methods how to do that. One way. Calculate the coordinates of its Vertex. Then...does this parabola open up or downward?

Comment: It does not say if the parabola opens up or downward

Comment: That's true. Because that is what YOU need to figure out.....from the given equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$-x^2+x-2=\dfrac{4x^2-4x+8}{-4}=\dfrac{(2x-1)^2+7}{-4}$$

Now, $(2x-1)^2+7\ge7$ for real $x$

Answer (score 2):

A general criterion:

The discriminant is negative (hence no real root, hence constant sign) and the leading coefficient is negative. Or the constant term is negative.

Comment: What does the constant have to do with it?

Comment: If there's no real root, the leading and the  constant coefficients must have the same sign.

Comment: Ah I see, Then the word "Or" in the answer should be "and" otherwise it looks like there is alternating choice

Comment: It is  indeed a variant, whence the ‘or’ (not an exclusive one).